# Copy Map from the second element onwards to another Map

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have a map: `map<int , std::string> results` and I want to copy a part of this map in a second map `results2`.

For example I have:

```
results[0] = "A",
results[1] = "B",
results[2] = "C",
results[3] = "D"
```

And `results2` would then be for example `results2("B", "C", "D")`. So that it is the same from index 1 on.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: You say `results2` is a map, but your example doesn't specify it as a map. What do you *really* want? The more effort you put into phrasing your question, the likelier it's to be answered. The onus is on you to be clear, not on us to divine what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with `insert` and `std::next`.
`std::map` does not have random access iterators, only bidirectional iterators, so there's no `+ n` operation. So `std::next` is required.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> results, results2;
    results = {{1, "A"}, {2, "B"}, {3, "C"}, {4, "D"}};
    results2.insert(std::next(results.begin()), results.end()); //from second element onwards

    for(auto const& m: results)
      std::cout << m.first << ' ' << m.second << ' ';

    std::cout << '\n';

    for(auto const& m: results2)
      std::cout << m.first << ' ' << m.second << ' ';

}
```

[See Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d214de9667e1f07)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to copy a part of this map in a second map

This is straightforward using iterators and constructing a 'second map'

```
std::map<int, std::string> result2(results.find("B"), results.end());
```

Will copy anything from and including "B" to the end.

Comment: What error? It will just be an empty map if `"B"` isn't found.